# Improper integral involving trigonometric function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, intuition

I was wondering what happens when evaluating an improper integral involving a trigonometric function where the denominator is a rational function with a zero at $x=0$.

The example I have in mind is
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{sin(ax)}{x(x-i)(x+i)} dx$$

If I rewrite the sine in terms of the exponential and then evaluate two integrals, one for the upper half-plane and one for the lower I have a problem because of the singularity at $z=0$ which seems to be in both halves of the plane. Do I treat it in both integrals then? Any suggestions/comments are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of avoiding to deal with the (redundant) singularity after spliting the integrals is to first differentiate w.r.t. $a$ and use Eulers identity

$$
I'(a)=\Re \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{e^{i a x}}{(x-i)(x+i)}
$$

Assuming that $a>0$ we have to close our contour of integration, which is a big semicircle , in the upper halfplane(for $a<0$ it is the other way round)

We get

$$
I'(a)=\Re(2\pi i \text{Res}(x=i))=\pi e^{-a}
$$

integrating back w.r.t. $a$ yields 
$$
I(a)=-\pi e^{-a}+C
$$

and the constant of integration is fixed by the requirement that $I(0)=0$

which brings us to our final result

> $$
> I(a)=\pi(1-e^{-a})
> $$

I leave the case $a<0$ to you

Comment: So for $a<0, I(a)= \pi (e^{-a} - 1)$ ? 
Also is there a factor $ \frac{1}{2} $ missing for your expression of $I'(a)$ ?
Anyway, thanks a ton!

Comment: it is $(e^a-1)\pi$ for $a<0$. why should be there a foctor of $1/2$?

Comment: The residue at $x=i$ is $\frac{e^{-a}}{2i}$ and theres a factor $\frac{1}{2i}$ from Eulers identity for the sine and one of these $\frac{1}{2i}$ cancels with the factor $2\pi i$ in the expression for $I'(a)$, right? So $I'(a)=2\pi i^2 \frac{1}{2i} \frac{e^{-a}}{2i} =\pi \frac{e^{-a}}{2} $.

Comment: eulers identiy yields a 1/2 because of the cosine so u a nearly right ;) i should go to bed...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Understandably, you are tired.

Comment: Nicely done!  +1 - Mark

Comment: @tired I added a solution that begins with partial fraction expansion, which works nicely here.

Comment: @fizicar There is no factor of $1/2$ missing from this answer.  I posted an alternative solution and obtained the same answer as this one.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use partial fraction expansion to write

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(ax)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\,dx-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\sin(ax)}{x^2+1}\,dx \tag 1$$

Now, the first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ can be evaluated by using Cauchy's Integral Theorem and writing

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\,dx&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\text{Im}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}\frac{e^{iax}}{x}\,dx+\int_\epsilon^\infty \frac{e^{iax}}{x}\,dx\right)\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(-\text{sgn}(a)\text{Im}\left(\int_\pi^0 \frac{e^{ia\epsilon e^{i\theta}}}{\epsilon e^{^{i\theta}}}\,i\epsilon e^{i\theta}\,d\theta\right)\right)\\\\
&=\pi\, \text{sgn}(a)
\end{align}$$

where we have tacitly used Jordan's Lemma to find that the contribution from integration over the infinite semi-circular contour integral that encloses the contour in a half plane is zero.

More simply, using the Residue Theorem, the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ becomes

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\sin(ax)}{x^2+1}\,dx=2\pi i \,\text{sgn}(a)\,\text{Im}\left(\text{Res}\left(\frac{ze^{iaz}}{z^2+1},z= i \text{sgn}(a)\right)\right)=\text{sgn}(a)\pi e^{-|a|}$$

where again, one can use Jordan's Lemma to show that the contribution from integration over the infinite semi-circle is zero.

Putting everything together yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(ax)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx=\pi\, \text{sgn}(a)\left(1-e^{-|a|}\right)}$$